# How is TDMA implemented to create time slots?

Tags: tdma

How is TDMA implemented to create time slots and radiate modulated audio signals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking how TDMA works? This has the potential to be a very big question. I'm just going to cover the basics, then offer up some links so you can learn more.

At a high level, TDMA (Time Division Multiple Access) simply means that multiple users share a communications channel by taking turns transmitting and receiving. This channel is usually considered to be a mobile radio channel, but it can just as easily be something wired like Ethernet.

Time is divided into slots, and certain terminals can only transmit in certain slots.

As for the specifics of how those slots are assigned, that is largely dependent on application, and that's where things can get really tricky.

In a simple application, each device on the channel can simply listen for other devices transmitting and wait until the channel is free before attempting a transmission. This is called [Carrier Sense Multiple Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access), and it isn't seen much outside of simple systems. Something slightly more advanced than this was used in early (10BASE2/10BASE5) Ethernet systems.

Packet-based systems like the early [ALOHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALOHAnet) system are much easier to study than modern protocols and are very useful for educational purposes. Essentially, if two or more users attempt to transmit at the same time, a collision has occurred and the stations will attempt a retransmission later at some future random interval. The Slotted ALOHA variant can be considered a form of slotted TDMA, as transmissions can only occur at the start of each timeslot.

Things get easier if you have a central base station which can assign time slots to avoid collisions. The gist of it is this: synchronize all mobile stations to a common time slot clock, and assign timeslots based on need. Actual implementations can be much more complex, of course.